# cannot import some of springframework libraries after upgrading spring to 5.3.28

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a maven project java 8 and I used to work with spring 5.3.26 and recently I upgraded my spring version to 5.3.28.
since than some springframework libraries are mot imported such as

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
```

[image]

below you can see all my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

anyone has an idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your IDE issue only. If you are using IntelliJ Idea, goto Maven view and try refreshing the maven project.

Also try running the build manually by running `min clean compile`.

If still issue persists, try invalidating the cache and restart.

Comment: thanks! I invalidating the cache and restart, and it worked!